# How to improve vector insert time

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, vector

I have **CSV** file. Which contain the **1086098** lines of logs. I have written c++ code. where i search for some text and based on founding i report the issues to the respective owner.

Implementation Details

1. Load all the file logs to std::vector.
2. Search in the vector at run time.

Problem : **push_back** in the std::vector takes **1683087** ms time. How can i improve on this time.
          Any other suggestion is welcome.

```
std::vector<std::string> complete_log;

bool LoadFileToVector(const std::string& str) {
  std::string needle = str;
  std::ifstream fin(needle.c_str());
  std::string line;
  bool found = false;

  if (fin.is_open()) {
    if (!is_empty(fin)) {
      fin.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit);

      try {
        while (getline(fin, line)) {
          complete_log.push_back(line);

        }

        for (const auto& text : start_check) {

          found = false;
          for (auto elem : complete_log) {
            if (elem.find(text) != std::string::npos) {
              basic_result[text] = true;
              found = true;
            }
          }
          if (!found)
            basic_result[text] = false;
        }

      } catch (std::ifstream::failure& FileExcep) {
        std::cout << "Caught an exception = " << FileExcep.what() << std::endl;
        fin.close();
        return false;
      } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "Unkown Exception/n";
      }
    } else {
      std::cout << "Input file "<<needle<<" is Empty" << std::endl;
      fin.close();
      return false;
    }

    fin.close();
    return true;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Cannot open file to update map" << std::endl;
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Edited : My bad i din't mentioned. I am measuring whole function LoadFileToVector().

Comment: Perhaps temporary storage in a vector isn't the right choice here? Perhaps read line by line (like you do now) but then check each line as you read it. Then you also don't have to iterate over (possibly) all the lines in the file twice like you do now.

Comment: Are you sure that it is `push_back` that takes that time and not `getline`?

Comment: yes push_back and std::find takes more time in the above code.

Comment: And preallocate, and use `for (const auto& elem` instead of making a copy of each line. Btw there's no need to explicitly call `close()`. And `needle` isn't really needed, and `basic_result` isn't defined, etc

Comment: Just did a small benchmark, reading a file with two million randomly generated lines (a little less than double your file, file-size is about 613MiB), and using plain `std::getline` and `push_back` in a loop (exactly like yours) it took only around 1300 milliseconds (on an old spinning-platter disk). So I kind of doubt your numbers. How do you measure? Are you measuring the whole `LoadFileToVector` function?

Comment: Sorry My bad I didn't mention this point. Yes i am measuring whole loadFileToVector method.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you:

1. Load all data into the string and use it for search. If you are using push_back with vector and strings, every time vector allocates memory if there is not enough and string allocates memory always. Each allocate is "new" call which is system call and requires switching to kernel mode (a lot of time lost, especially if the log is big)
2. Separate download and search processes just for good codestyle

As your question is about reading file performance, I didn't improve the search process. But if it will be not good enough for you, you can use threads. It is safe as long as you do not change the logs string.

```
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

/*
    logs.txt

    error
    error1
    no error
    you are breathtaking
    error 3
*/

std::array<std::string, 3>  start_check = { "error1", "error2", "error3" };
std::array<bool, 3>         basic_result;

std::string LoadLogs(const std::string& sFileName)
{
    std::ifstream fin(sFileName.c_str());
    fin >> std::noskipws;

    std::string sRet = "";

    if (!fin.is_open())
        std::cout << "Cannot open file to update map" << std::endl;
    else
        sRet = std::string(std::istream_iterator<char>(fin), std::istream_iterator<char>());

    if (sRet.empty())
        std::cout << "Input file " << sFileName << " is Empty" << std::endl;

    return sRet;
}

int main()
{
    std::string sLogs = LoadLogs("logs.txt");

    if (!sLogs.empty())
        for (int i = 0; i < start_check.size(); i++)
            basic_result[i] = sLogs.find(start_check[i]) != std::string::npos;

    /*
        basic_result

        true
        false
        false
    */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Regarding your 1.  The OP wanted to have "Load all the file logs to std::vector" of strings. Your 2.   Searching is one statement. So, I am not sure if a separate function or whatever would make more sense. And performance wise the separation is a downgrade. You need then to iterate again and again over all already read data. 3. I would not recommend to use threads for that.   But all this is just my humble opinion. No need to follow my advise at all. There are 1000 possibilities . . .

Comment: @ArminMontigny nope, OP wanted to "search for some text", and "Load all the file logs to std::vector" is implementation detail, which decrease performance. 
threads would work just fine if data is huge, why don't you like this idea?

Comment: Op stated: "I have CSV file. Which contain the 1086098 lines of logs. I have written c++ code. where i search for some text and based on founding i report the issues to the respective owner.". I can imagine, that he wants to do something with the lines after finding a tag in it, i.e use sregex_token_iterator for splitting up the line. And I compared solutions. As said, I run my programm in <800ms. That's not too bad. And most important, this is just my very humble opinion and there are millions of possible different solutions. So, yours is as good as mine or better. Whatever. No need to argue.

Comment: And to show what IMHO mean, I will upvote youre answer +1. Then you are the top hit here.

Answer (score 3):

I made a short evaluation for you.

I have written a test program, that first creates a test file. I put the search strings (integer counters) at the end of the line, so that the find function is maximum slow.

Then I did several improvement methods:

1. I switch on all compiler optimizations
2. For the vector, i use `reserve` to avoid reallocations
3. Reading from the stream is drastically improved by setting a bigger input buffer
4. I changed the search algorithm to avoid double iteration

With all this I read all lines and search for the search strings in 800ms, so below 1s.

Please see and check, if you can implement one of my ideas for your solution

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

constexpr size_t NumberOfExpectedLines = 1'086'098;
constexpr size_t SizeOfIOStreamBuffer = 1'000'000;
static char ioBuffer[SizeOfIOStreamBuffer];

const std::string fileName{ "r:\\log.txt" };

void writeTestFile() {
    if (std::ofstream ofs(fileName); ofs) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < NumberOfExpectedLines; ++i)
            ofs << "text,text,text,text,text,text," << i << "\n";

    }
}

bool LoadFileToVector(
    const std::string& fName, 
    const std::vector<std::string>& searchStrings, 
    std::vector<std::string>& completeLog,
    std::map<std::string,bool>& basicResult) {

    if (std::ifstream ifs(fName); ifs) {

        // Speed up things
        completeLog.reserve(NumberOfExpectedLines);
        ifs.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(ioBuffer, SizeOfIOStreamBuffer);

        // Read all files and search. Terminate, if we found all search strings
        for (std::string line{}; std::getline(ifs, line); ) {

            // Search for at least one occurence of a search string in the line
            if (auto search = std::find_if(searchStrings.begin(), searchStrings.end(),
                [&line](const std::string& s) {return line.find(s) != std::string::npos; });
                search != searchStrings.end()) {

                // If found, save result
                basicResult[*search] = true;
            }
            // Store read line
            completeLog.push_back(std::move(line));
        }
    }
    return  basicResult.size() > 0;
}

int main() {

    // writeTestFile();

    std::vector<std::string> searchStrings{"100000","500000","800000"};
    std::vector<std::string> completeLog{};
    std::map<std::string, bool> basicResult{};

    // TIme measurement start
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    LoadFileToVector(fileName, searchStrings, completeLog, basicResult);

    // Time measurement evaluation
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
    // How long did it take?
    std::cout << "Elapsed time:       " << elapsed.count() << " ms\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Maybe it will help you during refactoring

Comment: I want to test the time. But your code has  compile time error.

Comment: I am using VS2019 with C++17 enabled. Language is C++2017. The program compiles and rund without any error on my machine. What are you using or what error do you see?

Comment: i am on linux g++11

Comment: Ya i used c++17 :   load.cc: In function ‘void writeTestFile()’:
load.cc:19:23: error: expected primary-expression before ‘ofs’
     if (std::ofstream ofs(fileName); ofs) {
                       ^
load.cc:19:23: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘ofs’
load.cc:19:38: error: ‘ofs’ was not declared in this scope
     if (std::ofstream ofs(fileName); ofs) {
load.cc: In function ‘bool LoadFileToVector(const string&, const std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, bool>&)’:

Comment: load.cc:32:23: error: expected primary-expression before ‘ifs’
     if (std::ifstream ifs(fName); ifs) {
                       ^
load.cc:32:23: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘ifs’
load.cc:32:35: error: ‘ifs’ was not declared in this scope
     if (std::ifstream ifs(fName); ifs) {

Answer (score 1):

The vector is extended by inserting new elements before the element at the specified position, effectively increasing the container size by the number of elements inserted.

This causes an automatic reallocation of the allocated storage space if -and only if- the new vector size surpasses the current vector capacity.

Because vectors use an array as their underlying storage, inserting elements in positions other than the vector end causes the container to relocate all the elements that were after position to their new positions. This is generally an inefficient operation compared to the one performed for the same operation by other kinds of sequence containers (such as list or forward_list).

The parameters determine how many elements are inserted and to which values they are initialized:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 

using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 

    // initialising the vector 

    vector<int> vec = { 10, 20, 30, 40 }; 



    // inserts 3 at front   

    auto it = vec.insert(vec.begin(), 3); 

    // inserts 2 at front  

    vec.insert(it, 2); 

    cout << "The vector elements are: ";  

    for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it) 
        cout << *it << " "; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Avoid non portable `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`. and avoid `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Hm, I wondering why you are talking about insert. Maybe there is a misunderstanding. The OP is alread using push_back. And the simple solution is just to use reserve. Maybe you have a misunderstanding. Or maybe me, who knows . . .

Answer (score 1):

Shameless self plug: I'm the maintainer of a C++11 compatible CSV parser [which you can find here](https://github.com/vincentlaucsb/csv-parser). It uses separate threads to read from disk and parse, and optimizations which reduce the amount of memory allocations.

### If you don't want to use my parser

It appears that you don't actually use the delimiters in the CSV for anything, so you probably won't benefit from my parser. But from my lessons learned there are two avenues I can see you using.

### Solution 1: Avoid storing the entire file

As others have mentioned, it appears that you're doing line-by-line processing which doesn't require storing the entire file in memory. If so, I would just `getline()` into a string (like you do at the top of your loop), process it, and then repeat without `push_back()`-ing anything.

#### Why not?

`std::vector` is a fancy wrapper around an array which does useful things like expand when the capacity of the array is outgrown. The price of this convenience is that the contents of the old array have to be copied, and `malloc()` has to be called to create a bigger array. The bigger the array, the bigger the `malloc()` request.

std::string is a fancy wrapper around C-style character arrays and works similarly to std::vector. As you can see, creating `std::vector<std::string>`s is just memory allocations on top of memory allocations which is problematic because malloc() isn't optimized for a bunch of small allocations.

### Solution 2: Use a giant `std::string`

If for some reason you have to store the entire log as well as process each line individually, I would concatenate everything into a giant `std::string` and use a separate array to store the index of where each new line began. This way, you can create `std::string_view`s over each individual row. I would call `std::string::reserve()` to prevent any unnecessary re-allocations down the time.

In my experience this method is a lot faster than using an `std::vector` with lots of `std::string`s.

### Solution 2+: Threads

Your problem can be rearranged to fall under the producer/consumer pattern where one thread pushes a string into a buffer where another thread performs searching on it. I would personally only use multiple threads if other suggestions don't work since reducing dynamic memory allocations can have a **huge** performance impact.

### Other Notes

- Since it appears you only care if a certain search term appears **once** in the text, I would remove that term from the search list once it's been found. For example, if you find 10/15 search terms in the first 100 lines of text and you have 1,000,000 lines worth of log, then that's roughly 10 * 1,000,000 = 10,000,000 `find()` operations you won't have to perform.
- Avoid using global variables in C++. There's only a handful of valid use cases for them and this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the same format you have and you always know the number of lines for the vector, you can use `.reserve()`.

Example:

```
std::vector<std::string> complete_log;

bool LoadFileToVector(const std::string& str) {
  std::string needle = str;
  std::ifstream fin(needle.c_str());
  std::string line;
  bool found = false;

  if (fin.is_open()) {
    if (!is_empty(fin)) {
      fin.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit);

      complete_log.reserve(1086098);
      try {
        while (getline(fin, line)) {
          complete_log.push_back(line);

        }

        for (const auto& text : start_check) {

          found = false;
          for (auto elem : complete_log) {
            if (elem.find(text) != std::string::npos) {
              basic_result[text] = true;
              found = true;
            }
          }
          if (!found)
            basic_result[text] = false;
        }

      } catch (std::ifstream::failure& FileExcep) {
        std::cout << "Caught an exception = " << FileExcep.what() << std::endl;
        fin.close();
        return false;
      } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "Unkown Exception/n";
      }
    } else {
      std::cout << "Input file "<<needle<<" is Empty" << std::endl;
      fin.close();
      return false;
    }

    fin.close();
    return true;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Cannot open file to update map" << std::endl;
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Note the addition of `complete_log.reserve(1086098);`

However, other suggestions correctly point out that you could avoid storing all of the lines by simply processing each line as you have it and *not* store it.

This might involve inverting your bottom two loops. This might not be correct (I'm not compiling it), but it would look something like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> complete_log;

bool LoadFileToVector(const std::string& str) {
  std::string needle = str;
  std::ifstream fin(needle.c_str());
  std::string line;
  bool found = false;

  if (fin.is_open()) {
    if (!is_empty(fin)) {
      fin.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit);

      for (const auto& text : start_check) {
        basic_result[text] = false;
      }
      try {
        while (getline(fin, line)) {

          for (const auto& text : start_check) {    
            if (line.find(text) != std::string::npos) {
              basic_result[text] = true;
            }
          }
        }


      } catch (std::ifstream::failure& FileExcep) {
        std::cout << "Caught an exception = " << FileExcep.what() << std::endl;
        fin.close();
        return false;
      } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "Unkown Exception/n";
      }
    } else {
      std::cout << "Input file "<<needle<<" is Empty" << std::endl;
      fin.close();
      return false;
    }

    fin.close();
    return true;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Cannot open file to update map" << std::endl;
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```